# unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++

I am about two weeks into learning c++ and have decided to start a football simulation game. I have made a class called player and since then I have been getting a compilation error. However, even if I comment out the class I still get the error:

1>football1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall player::player(void)" (??0player@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _wmain

Here is the code:

```
// football.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#define _WIN32_WINNT  0x0500
#include <windows.h>
#include <Wincon.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class player{
private:
    static const int quarterbackspeed=10;
public:
    player();
    int ret(){return quarterbackspeed;}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //maximize console window
    HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    ShowWindow(hWnd,SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);  
    //DECLARE FOOTBALL FIELD
    char field[27][57];
    //declare sidelines x=0,x=51,y=0,y=121
    int times=0;
    for(int declarex=0;times<2;declarex=26){
        for(int declarey=0;declarey<57;declarey++){
            field[declarex][declarey]='x';}times++;}
    times=0;
    for(int declarey=0;times<2;declarey=56){
        for(int declarex=1;declarex<26;declarex++){
            field[declarex][declarey]='x';}times++;}
    //declare north endzone
    for(int declarey=1;declarey<3;declarey++){
        for(int declarex=1;declarex<26;declarex++){
            field[declarex][declarey]='*';}}
    //declare south endzone
    for(int declarey=54;declarey<56;declarey++){
        for(int declarex=1;declarex<26;declarex++){
            field[declarex][declarey]='*';}}
    //declare playing field
    for(int declarex=1;declarex<26;declarex++){
        for(int declarey=3;declarey<54;declarey++){
            field[declarex][declarey]=' ';}}
    //DECLARE PLAYERS
    player manning;
    cout<<manning.ret();
    //display field
    for (int declarey=0;declarey<57;declarey++){
        cout<<endl;
        for (int declarex=0;declarex<27;declarex++){
            cout<<field[declarex][declarey];}}

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared a constructor for the `player` class, but have provided no body. Provide a body to the class and that'll fix the error.

e.g. Inside the class

```
player() {}
```

or outside the class:

```
player::player() {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Errors like this beg you to develop on smaller pieces. You're trying to do too much at once, eschew the user interface and work on getting your player class to work first; you'll thank me later.

Answer (score 1):

Give the `player` constructor a function definition like

```
player()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the constructor of `player`. Try `player() { }` instead of the current `player();`